# Event management with Backbone.Marionette - Do I need to manually call stopListening for child views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling, marionette

I'm working inside of the Backbone.Marionette framework and I'm currently closing a Layout.

As an example, I've got something like:

```
var ForegroundView = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    el: $('body'),

    events: {
        'click': function (event) {
            this.close();
        }
    },

    regions: {
        rightBasePaneRegion: '#right-base-pane-region'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.rightBasePaneRegion.show(new RightBasePaneView({
            model: Player
        }));
    }
});
```

Player is a Backbone.Model which is already defined. RightBasePaneView is a Layout and a (simplified) version of it looks akin to:

```
var RightBasePaneView = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({

        modelEvents: {
            'change:state': function(){ console.log("Hello world."); }
        },

        //  TODO: Why do I have to do this manually? I thought Marionette handled this for me?
        onClose: function () {
            console.log("Right base pane model onClose start:", this.model._events['change:state'].length);
            this.stopListening(this.model);
            console.log("Right base pane model onClose end:", this.model._events['change:state'].length);
        }
});
```

Now, according to the [Marionette.Layout documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md), the ForegroundView's close event will cause RightBasePaneView to close:

> Closing A Layout
>
> When you are finished with a layout, you can call the close method on
> it. This will ensure that all of the region managers within the layout
> are closed correctly, which in turn ensures all of the views shown
> within the regions are closed correctly.
>
> If you are showing a layout within a parent region manager, replacing
> the layout with another view or another layout will close the current
> one, the same it will close a view.
>
> All of this ensures that layouts and the views that they contain are
> cleaned up correctly.

This description of closing a layout seems to say, "Don't worry about your child views, man. It's all good." In fact, I'm experiencing a need to manually call stopListening inside of my child view layout. During closing, my console looks like:

> Right base pane model onClose start: 5
>
> Right base pane model onClose end: 4

and if I don't call stopListening then I see the events continue to stack on my model.

This doesn't seem like correct behavior to me. Is it? Advice on how to properly handle sub-view event management with Marionette?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M5J8Q/1406/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `stopListening` manually. The problem is in your test suit.

If you look at [Marionette.View#close](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.view.js#L161-L184) you will see that [onClose](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.view.js#L177) calls before [Backbone.View#remove](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1070-L1074) that calls [stopListening](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1072) inside.

Here's a [fiddle with correct test](http://jsfiddle.net/M5J8Q/1406/).